# Python: blank lines added after splitting strings from text file

Tags: python, string, slice

I'm new to coding and python. I have text files with journal citations and I need to extract the journal issue, number (if applicable), and either the page numbers or article number (if there are no page numbers). I then want to write that information to separate lines in another text file.  For example (target extracts in bold):

J Antimicrob Chemother. 2012 Dec;**67(12):2843-7**. doi: 10.1093/jac/dks319. Epub 2012 Aug 14.

PLoS One. 2015 Jun 17;**10(6):e0128773**. doi: 10.1371/journal.pone.0128773. eCollection 2015. Erratum in: PLoS One. 2015;10(9):e0137697.  PLoS One. 2016;11(2):e0148706.

The code works well when the input is a single string, but when the input is multiple strings in a text file, the output file contains some anomalies.  Some of the sliced strings end with a ‘.’ and a new blank line is inserted after these strings.

Example input:

```
Trends Microbiol. 1997 Jul;5(7):268-71. Review.
Mol Microbiol. 1996 Sep:21(6):1117-23. Review.
Mol Microbiol. 1996 Aug;21(4):675-82. Review.
Res Vet Sci. 1996 Mar;60(2):168-72.
J Thero Biol. 1994 Jun 7;168(3):281-9.
J Biol Chem. 1993 Aug 25;268(24):18321-9.
J Bacteriol. 1993 May;175(10):3051-7.
Appl Environ Microbiol. 1988 Oct;54(10):2365-70.
Infect Immun. 1983 Oct;42(1):276-84.
```

Example output:

```
5.7.268-71
21.6.1117-23
21.4.675-82
60.2.168-72.

168.3.281-9.

268.24.18321-9.

175.10.3051-7.

54.20.2365-70.

42.1.276-84
```

I have tried to correct this by slicing the string again if it ends with a ‘.’ or ‘ ‘, but for some reason this only works with single strings.  I would appreciate any suggestions you have as to what I am doing wrong here.

```
slice_words = ['. doi', 'Epub', 'No abstract available', 'Erratum', 'Review', '. eCollection']

char_cleanup = ['). pii: ', ':', ').']

def string_processing(string):
    string = string[string.index(";")+1:]

    for i in slice_words:
        if i in string:
            string = string[:string.index(i)]

    for j in char_cleanup:
        if j in string:
            string = string.replace(j, '.')

    string = string.replace('(', '.')

    while string.endswith('.') or string.endswith(' '):
        string = string[:-1]

    return string

f = open("reference_strings_OUT.txt", 'w')

with open("reference_strings_IN.txt") as g:
    for line in g:
        string = line
        f.write(string_processing(string))
        f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: These are probably newlines in the text file after a period. Just do `line =line.strip()` before splitting.

Comment: Many thanks Claudio, the script now works fine with that alteration.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string = 'J Antimicrob Chemother. 2012 Dec;67(12):2843-7. doi: 10.1093/jac/dks319. Epub 2012 Aug 14'

subString = string[string.index(";")+1::]
subString = subString[0:subString.index(".")]
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks. Your code does work, but for single strings only.  This was also the case for the code I posted.  The problem is when I have a text file containing lots of these strings, it introduces blank lines in the output (see example input and output).